# Elfinder maxFileSize configuration

Tags: javascript, php, elfinder

I am trying to configure elfinder maxfilesize option in connector.php array options but still I am getting this error:

```
File exceeds maximum allowed size.
```

Here is My Configuration in connector.php:

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',                 // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),                // All Mimetypes not allowed to upload
            'uploadAllow'   => array('image', 'text/plain','application/vnd.ms-excel','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream','application/zip, application/octet-stream'),// Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` allowed to upload
            'uploadOrder'   => array('deny', 'allow'),      // allowed Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` only
            'accessControl' => 'access',                    // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL),
            'uploadMaxSize' => 1000000,
        )
    )
);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is your server? apache? nginx?

Comment: I am using apache.I configure php.ini also

Comment: what is the value `php_value upload_max_filesize` in `.htaccess`? or `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`?

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov I solved with apache php.ini now.Thanks for your trying helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 'roots' => array(
            array(
                'uploadMaxSize'=>'200KB',
                'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
                'path' => DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/',                // path to files (REQUIRED)
                'URL' => $domain . 'image/catalog/',
                'tmbPath' => DIR_IMAGE . 'elfinder_tmb',
                'tmbURL' => $domain . 'image/elfinder_tmb/',
                'tmbSize' => 100,
                'tmbCrop' => false,
                'tmbBgColor' => '#ffffff',
                'mimeDetect' => 'internal',
                'defaults' => array('read' => true, 'write' => true/*,'locked'=>true*/),
                'imgLib' => 'auto',
                'winHashFix' => DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR !== '/', // to make hash same to Linux one on windows too
                'uploadAllow' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml',
                    // "особые" типы древних IE добавил на всякий случай sitecreator
                    'image/pjpeg', 'image/webp', 'image/x-png'),
                'uploadDeny' => array('all'),
                'uploadOrder' => array('allow, deny'),
            )

        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.